# Multiple draw data annual monthly data by grouping years

Tags: r, graph, time-series

I need a graph by grouping years (2030-2040, 2041-2050, 2051-2060) based on months (X axis should be on months, Y axis Discharge values (Observed, RCP 4.5 Simulated, RCP 8.5 Simulated)). I need a graph like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6CVh.png) and my data like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZyjR.png)

Thank you for your help

Best wishes,

Ayfer

```
library(ggplot2)
dataclimate<- read.csv('ComparasionData.csv')
dataclimate <- data.frame(
  MONClimate = paste(rep(2030:2080,each = 12), month.abb),
  RCP.4.5.Simulated = sample(seq()


MonthRCP45<-dataclimate$MONClimate
RCP45<-dataclimate$RCP.4.5.Simulated
YearRCP45<-dataclimate$YEARClimate

  ### specify month on x axis and fuel on y axis
  ggplot(aes(x = MonthRCP45, y = RCP45)) +
  ### add lines per year (since the x axis is defined as factor, groups is necessary)
  geom_line(aes(col = YearRCP45, group = YearRCP45)) +
  ### add additional points
  geom_point(aes(col = YearRCP45)) +
  ### match axis title
  labs(
    x = 'Months', y = 'Predicted'
  ) +
  ### axis text without scientific notation
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(big.mark = ',', decimal.mark = '.', accuracy = 0.1)) +
  ### position the legend underneath the plot
  theme(
    legend.position = 'bottom'
  )
```

Comment: I don't see a graph at https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6CVh.png, your first link.

Comment: Screenshots of data are not very helpful. For us to use that data in a potential solution, we'd have to type it in or use an OCR tool. It would be far more helpful if you could run `dput(head(dataclimate, 20))` (assuming here that 20 rows is representative) and paste the output into the body of your question. Then we can use that data directly, with the same data types and structure you have.